# Why .ModelProj does not have ProjectTypeGuid tag

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Recently I came across a `.ModelProj project`. This is an `architecture modelling project`.

When it failed to load in VS2012 professional (got the reason later, that it loads only in ultimate version), 
I tried to check its  `.modelProj` file in notepad.

There I noticed that this .proj file does not have `ProjectTypeGuid` tag defined.

I am even unable to find the ProjectTypeGuid tag for modelling project in following lists:
[List 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)
[List 2](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)

So, my question is what is the reason that `.ModelProj` lacks `ProjectTypeGuid` tag.
Anyone happens to know the reason, please answer.

Comment: You've got to ask the team that built the tool. The question is: why do you want to know? And what is `f088123c-0e9e-452a-89e6-6ba2f21d5cac`?

Comment: @CodeCaster: I want to know just out of curiosity & I asked it here because I was unable to find the reason after some googling.

Comment: @CodeCaster: also I am unable to get you statement 'team that built the tool'. I suppose Modelling project template etc is generated by VS2012 itself as its a VS project type. right! (note: that I do not have VS2012 ultimate to check it out myself)

Comment: "Why" questions about third party products/systems will only generally be answerable by team members of that third party who happened to be around when a decision was made. And that even presupposes that a decision has to be made - i.e. why do you think the "decision" not to include X in a particular file was even taken, versus the fact that maybe, no requirement to ever *include* X has ever arisen.